# Are randomly-generated passwords starting with "a" less secure?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

I generated a password recently for a new account and the first three characters were "aa1".

After exhausting all other attacks, a cracker would start brute forcing. On the assumption they'd start from "a", my password of "aa1" would be cracked faster than, say, "ba1", and that faster than, say, "za1".

This password was very long so this question is more theoretical than practical. (Unless password lengths are limited, of course...) Are my assumptions right about brute-forcing and passwords?

Comment: brute-force would probably be parallelized, so if you have 26 running attack instances, then the 1st starting lowercase letter does not change a thing, but the question is pretty interesting : )

Comment: It depends on the total length and character set used, the more the marrier. You must make sure a rainbow attack is not viable, you should check out this rainbow table calculator https://www.tobtu.com/rtcalc.php

Comment: *"Are my assumptions right about brute-forcing and passwords..."* - You probably need to provide more context. An attacker would likely run through a [password list](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists) with 1M or 10M passwords. If unsuccessful for the current user account, they would move to the next user account and use the same password list again. Also see Peter Gutmann's *[Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf)*.

Comment: If so, just use "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" as the safest password there is.

Comment: The answer is obviously 'yes'. You have reduced the search space.

Comment: @user207421 technically it depends.  If they replace the first three characters of their password with `zzz` then they have reduced the entropy.  If they have prepended `zzz` to the password they would otherwise generate, then they haven't increased entropy but have increased length, so small win.  Neither change will matter if someone is trying to crack the password though...

Comment: the "try-order" of most password-cracker i have seen yet is `aaa`, `baa`, `caa`, ..., `zaa`, `aba`,  `bba`, so it is worth to take also a look at the last characters of your password. you don't know which tool an attacker to get your password. but probably all tools start with `a`, `0` or something like that. so your password may be a little bit more secure if you simply add one or two characters "from the middle" (e. g. `m`) to the begin and to the end of your password to avoid the problem you describe.

Comment: You assumption that an attack will start with 'a' may be incorrect.

Comment: You assume that a brute-force attack is necessarily sequential, but we all know that if you limit any process to one thread of execution you can only achieve this much. An attacker that does a bruteforce attack will use multiple threads. When using multiple threads why would they divide the work so that password are selected sequentially? It even becomes complicated to dispatch the next password to a new thread efficiently... Much simpler to give thread1 all passwords that start with `a..d`, thread2 all passwords that start with `e..h` etc.

Comment: If everybody knows passwords starting with "a" are less secure, in a rational world people will never use them. Therefore, passwords starting with "b" are now less secure, for the same reason. Rinse and repeat. Conclusion: it is impossible for a secure password to have a first character at all :)

Comment: This is why any rational attacker brute forces passwords in *reverse:* start with `aaaaaaaa` as normal, but rather than `aaaaaaab` next, do `baaaaaaa`. ;)

Comment: @alephzero agreed. The only rational solution to securing your password is to not have a first character!

Comment: Clearly  "acorrecthorsebatterystaple"  is safer than "correcthorsebatterystaple" but not as safe as "manycorrecthorsebatterystaples"

Comment: for any non-trivial cracking, the search order is not linear. but, it occurs to me that you could try to intentionally engineer your password to skew towards less common character sequences in order to come up "later" on in the search, under the assumption that the attacker will try to optimize their search to find more common passwords first. but that's a wild and pointless game, with any possible (very dubious) potential gains likely smaller than increasing the length of a random password by even a single character.

Comment: @dn3s Had the same idea and wrote an answer about it, but feel free to add on! https://security.stackexchange.com/a/213381/15756

Comment: I once had to brute force (my own) combination padlock.  I started at 4-0-0 because I was more likely to run into my combination faster (human nature being to avoid low numbers for this sort of reason).   Much later, I finally hit 3-9-8 and opened it...

Comment: @IMil OP has asked a very genuine question, don't get funny about it. It is really bad.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Paradoxically, "nocorrecthorsebatterystaples" is even more secure.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It would seem that it depends on how exactly the attacker is going to bruteforce your password. However, my opinion is that in the end it doesn't matter.

A serious attacker will never start from the beginning in alphanumeric order, from `aaaaaaaa` to `99999999`, unless they know they can do that in a reasonable time. If that's going to take them a thousand years, why should they use that method, knowing they will necessarily have to stop at, say, `cccccccc`? But if the attacker knows that they can try all the possibilities in a reasonable time, then it doesn't matter whether your password is among the first combinations or among the last, because in the end they will find it anyway (in a reasonable time).

Most passwords are still weak (say, your dog's name, plus maybe your date of birth, etc.) and the attackers don't like wasting too much time, let alone years to crack passwords. So what attackers normally do is use dictionaries and patterns. They will first try passwords like: `pass123`, `123pass`, `john90`, `john91`, `John92`, `JOHN93`, `123456`, `l1nux4dm1n`, etc. If every attempt with dictionaries and patterns fails, they might move on and assume that the password looks truly random. How long will it take to try **all** the possible passwords? If that can be done in a reasonable time, they might try them all (for example from `aaaaaaaa` to `99999999`). Otherwise if the attacker assumes that they will never be able to try them all, they might try to bruteforce the password with some random guesses (random strings, not ordered): `12hrisn589sjlf`, `9f2jcvew85hdye`, `otnwc739vhe82b`, etc. If the attacker is lucky they might find the password, sooner or later. However if the password is too strong, such that it would take them too many years to guess it, they had better give up or think of an alternative attack (phishing, shoulder surfing, keyloggers, etc.)

Comment: Indeed, I think that's what it really comes down to - the hacker is well aware of what their has rate is, and therefore what passwords they can crack in a reasonable amount of time.  Bruteforcing the full search space is either possible in a reasonable amount of time or it isn't, in which case they won't bother and it won't matter.

Comment: .... unless the random password generator came up with 'aardvark'

Comment: Hmm... this could mean that pre/post-pending a run of the same digits just to make the password longer without actually increasing the entropy might make it safer by taking it out of the "reasonable time" range?

Comment: @SamuelÅslund, if "banana123" is considered insecure, "banana123zzzzzzzzzzzzzz" is definitely more secure, but it's hard to say exactly how much that is going to help. Some attackers might try to append or prepend stuff to basic patterns (in the end, appending or prepending stuff is still going to be a pattern), but there's no way to know. The best practice, and the only one that's guaranteed to be secure, it to use passwords that have real entropy and don't rely on tricks, mnemonics, and password reuse.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund Entropy is about chaos, not raw number ranges. The best way I've heard it described is take you password, and black out one item at a time (so Banana would become Ban-na->B-n-na). How many can you take away before you can guess the removed parts with a high degree of certainty? That is pattern predictability. And the more predictable your pattern, the less Entropy (chaos) it actually contains. This lack of actual entropy is why text can be compressed so well in archives. (And why random characters with no relation to each other contain more entropy than words of the same length)

Comment: Perhaps this is a reason to have hamsters instead of dogs. A dog lives 10-13 years (roughly) while a hamster lives 2-2.5 years. Using hamster names instead of dog names increases the search space by a factor of 5?

Comment: @Tezra that's one way to measure entropy in human language, but entropy itself is a complicated topic with varying definitions in different fields (physics, computers, information theory, etc...)

Comment: @ConorMancone But all of those definitions boil down to more entropy means less predictability. With passwords, we talk about entropy as how predictable a pattern is. So by definition if you can redact part of your password, and can quickly guess (2-3 tries) what the redacted part was based on the surrounding context, you have reduced the entropy. "314159265359" is not human language, but it is also very predictable (pi). It's a way to measure pattern predictability. Human language is just a subset of patterns you can apply it to.

Comment: @doneal24 Also, dog and cat names are often registered, if nowhere else than at least with a local veterinarian, which provides a social-engineering weak point.  Hardly anyone registers hamsters.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, an attacker may try bruteforcing "aaaaaaa" to "ccccccc" if it gives them a 1/12 chance to earn more than 12 times their investment.

Comment: @doneal24 On top of that, hamster1234 is a lot more secure than dog1234 by size alone.

Comment: And  in the end, it doesn't even maaattee-e-eeer.

Answer (score 28):

### Entropy

Entropy is really the biggest concern, and entropy is determined by the amount of randomness in your password generation process.

Let's use an 18 character password as an example.  We'll look at alphanumeric characters only (62 possible characters).  This gives:

`log2(62**18) = 107` bits of entropy

If you decide to always convert the first 3 characters to Z to make it harder to bruteforce then you have effectively removed 3 random characters from your password, leaving you with:

`log2(62**15) = 89` bits of entropy

Which is about a factor of 1,000,000 weaker.  Of course, both are still [absolutely](https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/1x50xl/time_and_energy_required_to_bruteforce_a_aes256/) and [completely](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year) impossible to bruteforce, so if someone is trying to brute force your password I wouldn't worry.

### Cracking strong passwords is impossible

However, it's worth emphasizing how impossible it is to brute force such a password (just in case my links didn't convince you).  A top of the [line MD5 hashing rig](https://securityledger.com/2012/12/new-25-gpu-monster-devours-passwords-in-seconds/) can try 200 billion hashes per second.  It's blazing fast (which is why MD5 isn't supposed to be used for passwords).  Even your weaker password (when you replaced the first three characters with `z`) has 7.6e26 possible combinations.  At 200 billion hashes per second it will *only* take 120 **MILLION** years to try all password possibilities if the password was hashed with MD5.  I don't think you have anything to worry about.

### The impact of `aa`

So, is it better to start with "higher" characters to make it harder for someone to brute force your password?  Maybe, maybe not.  If an attacker happens to start at the beginning of the alphabet then sure, yours will get cracked "faster" (although still not in this lifetime).  However, there are no guarantees that someone attempting a brute force would operate in that particular order.  As a result, it's impossible to guess whether or not a password starting with `aa` may be more crackable.  Again though, if you use a long random password, there is effectively zero chance that it will get hacked.  So I wouldn't worry about it.  When it comes to passwords [length is king](https://crambler.com/password-security-why-secure-passwords-need-length-over-complexity/).

### Kerckhoff's Principle (h/t Adonalsium)

I think that Kerchkhoff's principle is very applicable here.  This is, in a sense, a core "tenet" of security.  The idea behind Kerchkhoff's principle is that the security of a system should be based on one, and only one, secret/key.  The idea is that the more "parts" are needed to keep a system secure, the more likely it is that some parts will get leaked and a security breach will happen.  When we're talking about passwords it's quite clear what the "key" is: the password.  Specifically, a long and random one.  As discussed above, it's really all you need.  By adding further "rules" on top of your random password you're really just giving potential hints to make it easier for an attacker who is targeting you to guess your password.

Comment: This sort of "clever" reduction of entropy by removing "easy to guess" patterns [goes all the way back to the Engima machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis_of_the_Enigma#Operating_shortcomings). For example: no rotor could be in the same spot two days in a row; no two plugboard connections could be adjacent; no rotor settings could repeat in a month. Once the codebreakers worked out what the procedure was these all *reduced* the combinations they had to search.

Comment: @Schwern that's possibly the best comment ever.  I think it would deserve to be an answer itself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96200/discussion-on-answer-by-conor-mancone-are-randomly-generated-passwords-starting).

Answer (score 20):

> After exhausting all other attacks, a cracker would start brute
>   forcing.

Says who?

There are only two scenarios in which brute-forcing is actually a thing. One is when the attacker has the password hash and the other is when he has control of the software controlling the login because any non-totally-broken software wouldn't allow him to brute-force in the first place.

The most common case is that the attacker does have a password database. He will be using a cracker software like John the Ripper. He will have tested a few million possible passwords before he even starts with "aa". In most cases, at this point he already has cracked several thousand accounts because their password was "password" or "12345678". Or - to satisfy the dummy "password strength" checker - "Pass123!".

He probably won't bother letting his cracker run into the actual brute-force step, because he has better things to do with his time. And you actually don't know if brute-forcing would actually start at aa or not, because there's a good chance it wouldn't.

Your **real** problem is that as soon as you make rules about which passwords you consider "bad", you actually **reduce** the search space. Password policies are harmful, as it turns out. Look, the author of JtR even has [a page about that](https://openwall.info/wiki/john/policy) on his wiki. Of course the $$$ consultant who convinced your CISO to adopt his stupid password policy never read that page and probably doesn't even know JtR still exists. :-)

So no, "aa1" is not appreciably less secure than "zz9". Firstly because brute-forcing is the last weapon, not the first and secondly because there is no guarantee that the brute-force software actually starts at a and not at z. I would not start at a if I were to write one. I'd randomize the alphabet and use that, for example. Exactly because I'd figure people probably avoid "aaaaaaaa" as a password.

Comment: Sadly, according to https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords the password aaaaaaaa has indeed been used, leaked and broken over seventy thousand times. (zzzzzzzz comes in at 54k and llllllll at 7k.)

Comment: That's almost nothing, compared to, say, "password" with over 3.6 **million** times or "secret" (which is just 6 characters) with almost a quarter million. :-)

Comment: That's true. It's definitely not the worst password in the world. :)

Comment: Actually, a lot of attackers use brute force as their _first_ technique, although they'll only brute force, say, 4 characters before moving on to better attacks like dictionary and hybrid attacks.

Comment: The JtR wiki page you link to about password policies doesn't really back up your argument. It says that for an ASCII password of length 8, requiring at least 3 character classes only reduces the search space by 5.5%, "so it is a reasonable thing to do". Some authorities may assert that "password policies are harmful" but that particular page does not.

Comment: @IMSoP the point is that it **reduces** the search space, not enlarges it. That's counter-intuitive to most people.

Comment: Indeed. There's probably a better reference for that, though, as the one you linked to mostly assumes you already know and is just quantifying the effect.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the other answers are focusing on why a password starting with 'a' would not be less secure than any other starting letter because you're assuming that the attacker is doing it sequentially vs parallel, or because you're assuming they are starting from 'a,' when a skilled attacker might not. Because of these arguments, no starting letter is any less secure than another from a skilled attack.

However, I would argue that against a naive attacker, a password starting with 'a' is marginally less secure, due to the fact that they would be more likely to do it sequentially and starting from 'a' as a result of their lack of skill and experience.

In practice, though, like the other answers said, this won't make a difference because in practice, a long enough randomly generated password will likely never be able to be brute forced in a reasonable amount of time, and avoiding the letter 'a' would just narrow down the search space.

Answer (score 4):

When you assume a brute-force attack, a password starting in "a" might be weaker. If using "z" gets popular, this would be true for "a" and "z", what would make it more complicated to assess the risk.

Lets assume we know a character that is tried before others. Then the attacker only needs to test `1/26` of the search space. The solution is, to **make your password longer**. Not only when it starts with "a", but always.

A attacker will probably start with short passwords for a brute-force search*, so your longer one has much better protection. Even when he does not, he will need to test many more passwords before getting yours.

A dictionary attack or mixed attack may try "a", "aa", "aaaaaaaa" before trying "b", though. This is a mind game between the attacker and you, so choosing a random passphrase is the best approach and rejecting ones that may be in word lists is reasonable (but a random long password is unlikely to be in a wordlist, anyway).

`*` Testing all 1-8 char passwords needs only about twice the time as testing all 9 char passwords starting with "a", so it is reasonable to start with shorter ones, if there is a possibility that the password is short.

Comment: Why do you assume that a bruteforce attack will start at "a"?

Comment: @T.Sar I don't think it's an unreasonable assumption. You have to start somewhere and this is the first letter in the alphabet and in the ASCII/unicode table. It seems as likely a place as any (an attacker wouldn't want to have to keep state of each password they already checked, so there must be a sequence, i.e. it won't be random, and from experience, A is what did myself in my scriptkiddie days).

Comment: @T.Sar I followed the assumption in the question and based my answer on this assumption.

Comment: The number of 9-char passwords (N^9) seems to me about (N-1) times larger than the number of 1-8-char passwords (N^9-N)/(N-1), where N is the alphabet size. That is considerably larger (unless we are in the well-known case N=2). Am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, I mixed this up. I hope its correct now.

Answer (score 4):

## Thinking out of the box: Correcting for threat model

A lot of the existing answers already indicate that there is little to gain by simply avoiding the a, and that it is very easy to apply a 'fix' that actually makes your situation worse.

HOWEVER, conceptually it also feels wrong to ignore the attackers way of working completely. Therefore I present this solution direction, that should work in theory (but may be a bit hard to apply in practice):

> If your threat model defines an attacker is more likely to attack a pattern, it would be good to make the occurrance of this pattern less likely

Example:

1. Suppose you know there are common tools that brute force passwords from 'a' forward
2. Suppose these are typically configured by allocated time/tries, which happens to come out to them trying the 'a' more often than the 'z'
3. Suppose this results in the total number of made attacks against you by everyone in the world, this results in the 'a' being tried 2% more often than the other letters

In this case it would probably be good to make the 'a' 1% less likely

## Conclusion

If you have (and keep track of) the real threat against you, you should be able to slightly reduce the chance of your password being cracked. Unfortunately you would need a giant company to know the status at any time, and you would need to re-generate passwords every time the threat model changes. For instance because **the attackers also learn that you are correcting for the patterns** of last week.

In short, realize that you were conceptually right, but it is just impractical to implement properly.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, yes, if the cracking comes down to brute force, there might be a higher chance that a password starting with "a" will be checked before a password starting with "z". It's not necessarily true, but it may well be.

An important thing to understand about password entropy is that you have to calculate it wrt. the model the attacker will likely use to crack passwords, not wrt. the model you have used to generate it. For example, if you generated a completely random alphanumeric password and you got "passwordpassword123", it has the same "generation" entropy as any other random password of the same length. High "generation" entropy doesn't make it a good password though, as it has very low "cracking" entropy assuming typical dictionary attacks.

It's not unheard of discarding randomly generated passwords exactly for this reason. While discarding reduced the number of available passwords (and thus reduces password security), it avoids generating a password which would be very easy to crack.

Comment: "*It's not unheard of discarding randomly generated passwords*" Do you have an example? Aside from 4 digit PIN codes, I don't think I ever heard of anyone discarding weak random passwords. If your random password generator generates "passwordpassword123" before the heat death of the universe, it can't have been a good generator in the first place.

Comment: @Luc Or maybe you're just **really** lucky and need to go play the lottery...

Comment: @ConorMancone Not really. If you assume that all 8 billion people on this planet each create a new account every second (so they each generate a random 16-character password every second), it would still take 94 billion years before there is a 50% chance that someone generated "passwordpassword". If you were joking, then I fully agree with you, but I can't tell if you think there is a serious chance of this ;)

Comment: If your random password generator is generating easy to guess passwords, you may have inadvertently created something very special.  Maybe you could get it to write some Shakespeare next?  I'm sure it'll generate a few new works.

Comment: @Luc By that logic, winning with a lottery ticket numbered 1,2,3,4,5,6 would be "more lucky" than winning with a "random-looking" ticket. After 94 billion years, it's more likely that a particular target string comes up, but that doesn't mean you can rely on it not coming up sooner.

Comment: @SteveSether That's not really the point. What I'm trying to say is that the password isn't strong because it has a lot of entropy. It's strong because it takes a long time to crack.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to do something about it, all you could do (apart from increasing password length) would be to reject passwords beginning with an 'a'. Now you have removed 1/26th of possible passwords, and the attacker can crack the average password 26/25 times quicker.

...and now, the weakest passwords begin with a 'b'. Do we remove these and make 'c' the new weakest first character? You see where this is going.

The other answers have explained well why it doesn't matter, I just wanted to point out that trying to fix this by avoiding certain passwords is absurd.

Answer (score 3):

To add on to the many good answers here, it's worth noting that even where an attacker is using a brute-force attack (which is rare, given all the better options discussed), good tools don't do a sequential brute-force.

For example, the brute-force mode in John the Ripper (which @Tom mentions above) is called [Incremental Mode](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/doc/MODES#L92), and although it does cover the entire keyspace, it uses a frequency based model to cover the keyspace in a much more efficient order than a sequential A-Z attack would.

I also remember and older tool called PasswordsPro, which would do a sequential brute-force, but started at the end of the string rather than the start (aaaa, aaab, aaac, etc).